# Sick Betta fish whyyyy

Tags: betta

My beta has always been pretty active but for the past couple of weeks he’s been In a funk. He was floating at the top of his filter for a few days now he’s laying in the bottom of his tank I though he was dead. He’s in a five gallon tank with a snail, a java fern and a moss ball. He had a filter and a heater and I changed out his water thinking maybe that was the problem but nope he’s still acting weird and no he’s not eating well at all even though he’s normally excited about his bloodworms. Any suggestions?